# How can hide controls in Windows Form Application without hide base form

Tags: c#, forms

i'm sorry for poor English.

I have a form in my C# Winform Application. This form includes controls such as Label,TextBox...!
how can i hide Form without hide it's controls?!!

For example it use in create User Control such as DateTimePicker,...

how do work hidden and show calendar box in DateTimepicker?!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: `yourControl.Visible = false;` -1 and close vote. :)

Comment: you cant hide the form without hiding its controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this isn't possible since the form is the root element and making it invisible automatically hides the children inside,
you can cleverly customize the height and width somehow according to your needs.